# map 2 json file into a single json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have2 json files named Raw.json and ParamName.json I want to map these 2 json file into one.
**Raw.json**

```html
[
 {
  "p1": "989671267",
  "p2": "302",
  "p3": "Answered"
 }
]
```

**ParamName.json**

```html
[
 {
  "p1": "CLI",
  "p2": "DID",
  "p3": "Status
 }
]
```

I want to be looks like 
[
 {
   "CLI": "989671267",
   "DID": "302",
   "Status": "Answered"
 }
]

I have to use this in my angular2 smart table..Please anybody help.?

Comment: at least, post your code where you are loading those json files

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method in combination with `reduce` method.

```js
let array1=[
 {
  "p1": "989671267",
  "p2": "302",
  "p3": "Answered"
 },
 {
  "p4": "9896712671",
  "p5": "3021",
  "p6": "Answered1"
 }
]
let array2=[
 {
  "p1": "CLI",
  "p2": "DID",
  "p3": "Status"
 },
 {
  "p4": "CLI1",
  "p5": "DID1",
  "p6": "Status1"
 }
];
array2=array2.map(function(item,i){
  let itemKeys=Object.keys(item);
  let obj=itemKeys.reduce(function(obj,key){
    obj[item[key]]=array1[i][key];
    return obj;
  },{});
  return obj;
});
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: thank you Alexandru-lonut . This is really helpful . If you don't mind, please tell me how to store these new json to a file in it's proper format... Help me yaar.!

Comment: What technology do you used as server-side ?